# display blob text in grails

Tags: html, mysql, grails

I am trying to display blob stored in MySQL as html content in gsp page. Can anybody please help me on this and I am new to Grails.

What I am trying to do:

1. A 3rd party application is going to upload a file in MySQL as BLOB which is a report in HTML format.
2. In my GRAILS application, I am suppose to show all file names.
3. Once user click the file name, it is suppose to get the BLOB data and display the text in HTML format in gsp page.

What I have achieved till now:

1. index.gsp page shows file name, created date
2. Once user clicks the file name, show.gsp shows file name

What I need to achieve:

1. show.gsp should show the content of the file as HTML content.

A restriction:

1. I am not suppose to download the file in server drive and then display the file as HTML in gsp page.

I am using Grails: 2.3.7 on Windows 7 with MySQL 6.1.6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your controller action to get the file out of the db can look like:

```
def getFile( Long id ){
  def obj = YourDomain.get( id )
  response.setHeader 'Content-Type', 'text/html'
  response.setHeader 'Content-Disposition', "inline;filename=${obj.filename}"
  response.outputStream.withOutputStream{ it << obj.file }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the file is an html file you can store it as a TEXT dataType. This is the text version of a BLOB so you have TINYTEXT, TEXT, MEDIUMTEXT and LONGTEXT types.

You can declare the datatype in the domain class such as:

```
static mapping = {
    filedata sqlType: 'text'
}
```